# Mac SetFile to change date doesn't work correctely with variable

Tags: bash, macos, command-line

I'm trying to change the creation date of image files to the date of the file name.

A file is named like `20221115_125630_HDR.jpg` and since `touch -t` only changes the modified date, I'm trying out `SetFile -d`.

Here's my code:

```
for f in ./*.jpg ; do 
  t=${f##*/}
  date="'${t:4:2}/${t:6:2}/${t:0:4} ${t:9:2}:${t:11:2}:${t:13:2}'"
  SetFile -d $date $f 
done
```

Oddly enough, it changes the creation date to `16 December 2021  12:56` and when I plop in `echo` before the SetFile, it returns this:

```
SetFile -d '11/15/2022 09:10:26' ./20221115_091026_HDR.jpg
```

When I copy and paste this line, it sets the creation date to the correct date.

What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should quote `$date`, not the value you assign to it.

```
date="${t:4:2}/${t:6:2}/${t:0:4} ${t:9:2}:${t:11:2}:${t:13:2}"
SetFile -d "$date" "$f"
```